# Best Frontend for API RESTfull expres.js and mongodb?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ember.js, express, reactjs

I am beginning with node.js, mongodb ... I want to make a web application that connects to a mongodb and to create a CRUD product. I've created my API Restfull with express.js and mongodb. Now I have to do the frontend and I'm lost. For the Frontend I plan to use AngularJS, ReactJs or EmberJS but I do not know what should I choose to start, because I've never used any of these technologies and I would use it more easy to use and understand if possible (or if there are other, easier). Any tips?

Comment: You should just visit the websites for each of those.  Generally, they say what they are good for.

Comment: I was looking for someone to guide me a little with a manual or guide to get started

Comment: Angular is meant for CRUD applications, however the learning curve is a bit steep.   I don't have enough familiarity with the others to speak to them, though my understanding is react.js is heavily view-focused, so I believe you would still need some way to handle AJAX calls.

Comment: If you want to try and tackle angular, I have found this guide to be one of the best out there:
https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/

Comment: ok, thank you! :-) and for rect.'s? do you have a guide or something?

Comment: Just go to the react website.  They have a tutorial that takes you through building a small view.  In fact, you should probably do that with each of the three so you can get a feel for them.

Comment: I would recommend Ember.js - there is now a new ultra-fast rendering engine in production (will be very easy to implement when done), with similar performance as React.js. React is just a library for building user interfaces, so you would have to build a lot of the structure by yourself. With Ember you can choose to use Ember Data, which helps A LOT when dealing with Restfull server. Also the structure of the project in Ember looks quite transparent. Angular has a big drawback, being that the team is working on the Angular 2.0 which is a completely rewrite and with no backwards compatibility.

Comment: You can go to todomvc.com where Addy Osmani has made tutorials for most front end frameworks so you can really compare and find what you like. I have worked with angular and ember and I would recommend ember hands down. Angular has a long way to go with the 2.0 debacle and even then it doesn't use very standard design patterns. If you do try ember, make sure to use the ember-cli :)